# auto insert with mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

hi i have issue about mysql trigger, i have table as given below. how to make insert automatically on **add_id** field with trigger, when user insert trip_id, add_type, value.

```
CREATE TABLE `additional` ( `trip_num` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL ,  
                            `add_id` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL ,  
                            `add_type` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,  
                            `value` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL );
```

```
INSERT INTO `additional` (`trip_num`, `add_id`, `add_type`, `value`) VALUES 
('TRP0001', 'UM1', 'type 1', '50'), 
('TRP0001', 'UM2', 'type 1', '27'), 
('TRP0001', 'UB1', 'type 2', '250'), 
('TRP0002', 'UM1', 'type 1', '32'), 
('TRP0002', 'UB1', 'type 2', '300'), 
('TRP0002', 'UB2', 'type 2', '120'), 
('TRP0002', 'UL1', 'type 3', '120');
```

[here the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUV5v.jpg)

Comment: Pl provide what you have tried and also the sample data to be inserted

Comment: Replace the photo with textual CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts and show desired result in textual table form.

Comment: @Akina i just updated textual CRETAE TABLE + INSERT

Comment: do you mean those trigger executed on the same table ?

Comment: hi @RajenRaiyarela

i want automatically add_id with sequence when i insert other field

but add_id have condition like this :

if add_type = "type 1" then set add_id "UM"

if add_type = "type 2" then set add_id "UB"

if add_type = "type 2" then set add_id "UL"

Comment: Then you have to make that field optional in insert and then do an update trigger which executes after you insert data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi
BEFORE INSERT 
ON additional
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE counter INT;
SELECT 1 + COUNT(*) 
    INTO counter 
    FROM additional 
    WHERE trip_num = NEW.trip_num
      AND add_type = NEW.add_type;
SET NEW.add_id = CONCAT( CASE NEW.add_type WHEN 'type 1' THEN 'UM'
                                           WHEN 'type 2' THEN 'UB'
                                           WHEN 'type 3' THEN 'UL'
                                                         ELSE '??' END,
                         counter );
END;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ae9135c1b948dd055ab22b74d5d27e86)

PS. I have removed `add_id` from INSERT which cause to add DEFAULT value into CREATE TABLE. You may revert and assign any value to this field - it will be overwrited unconditionally.

Comment: i found error like this
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi
BEFORE INSERT 
ON additional
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE counter INT
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6